# Pass value from Child Form to Parent Form

Tags: vb.net

Something so simple has caused me to pull my hair out....

All I am trying to do is pass an entered value on a Child Form back to the Parent form either to a Public variable or text box but the value just won't pass back.

Parent Form code :

```
Private Sub cmb_pay_type_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmb_pay_type.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cmb_pay_type.SelectedItem = "شيك" Then
        Dim frm As New cheque_sent_add
        frm.XX.Text = 1
        frm.txt_cheque_value.Text = DFANEW.Text
        frm.txt_cheque_holder_name.Text = MORD.Text
        frm.txt_cheque_holder_phone.Text = PON.Text
        frm.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub

Public cheque_num As String
Public cheque_value As String
Public due_date As Date
Public bank_name As String
Public bank_branch As String
Public status As String
Public cheque_owner As String
Public cheque_holder_name As String
Public cheque_holder_phone As String
Public action_date As Date
Public note As String

Public insert As Boolean = False
```

and child form :

```
 If XX.Text = 1 Then

        DFAM.DFANEW.Text = txt_cheque_value.Text
        DFAM.cheque_num = txt_cheque_num.Text
        DFAM.cheque_value = txt_cheque_value.Text
        DFAM.due_date = due_date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        DFAM.bank_name = txt_bank_name.Text
        DFAM.bank_branch = txt_bank_branch.Text
        DFAM.status = cmb_status.SelectedItem
        DFAM.cheque_owner = txt_cheque_owner.Text
        DFAM.cheque_holder_name = txt_cheque_holder_name.Text
        DFAM.cheque_holder_phone = txt_cheque_holder_phone.Text
        DFAM.action_date = action_date.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
        DFAM.note = txt_note.Text

        DFAM.DFANEW.Enabled = False
        DFAM.insert = True

        Me.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

this what I'm using, i can show data if I open A new Parent form,
put I want to send back the values from the child to the already opens Parent form.

Comment: Pass the Parent Form existing instance to the Child Form constructor (in the Parent Form => `[Child].Show(Me)`). Assign the instance to a private field declared in the Child Form class scope and use it to reference the Parent (possibly using a Public method of the Parent that allows to set properties of its controls).

Comment: @Jimi can you explain  by simple code plz

Comment: People get in a tizzy because they think that forms are somehow special.  They're not.,  They're just objects like any other.  As such, you treat them like any other.  How do you usually get data into an object?  You set a property or you call a method and pass an argument.  This is no different.  If you want to pass the calling form into the called form then you assign it to a property or call a method and pass it as an argument.  Obviously you need to write that property or method yourself.  You know how to write a method or a property, right?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes I know how to write a method, I done multi way to fix this and all them didn't give me solution, can you show me a simple ??

thank you

Comment: If you already know how to write a method then you already have examples.  If you need to call this method and pass an argument then the method obviously needs a parameter, so write a method with a parameter of the appropriate type.

Comment: You might benefit from reading [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).  Be sure to read all three parts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

after searching and trying many ways, this how i solve the problem

adding module to the solution

and then add public  variables

```
Module Module1
  Public x1 As String
  Public x2 As String
End Module
```

the main form `Form1` :

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f2 As New Form2
    f2.ShowDialog()
  End Sub
End Class
```

and finally the child form `Form2` :

```
Public Class Form2
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      x1 = TextBox1.Text
      x2 = TextBox2.Text

      Form1.TextBox1.Text = x1
      Form1.TextBox2.Text = x2

      Me.Close()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Fiddling with code from another form from a child form is usually not a good solution.